# Teaching and making programming exciting to the novice

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, computer-science

I wanted to teach programming to a complete novice ( somebody who has a bachelor's degree in arts but never into programming).

I tried to introduce python but the response was something like, " Okay, it prints 1,2,3,.....or yes, it does fibonacci series but what is a use, I can do it easily, or my calculator does it, how is it useful". I tried to sell the grand idea with saying that, "Hey, you see the MS Office you use, it uses the same concept." but it did not work. Simply speaking, I could not create or show anything to appeal the novice into getting interested in programming. I showed the GUI I created using wxpython but was horrified to see that the code I wrote gave the novice nothing but horror.

Can anybody suggest a programming teaching approach or something related to programming or even some easy code that will make the novice believe that programming is cool, easy and fun to learn?

Comment: But programming is not cool, easy or fun to learn.  It is recondite, difficult and a struggle to learn.  Let your creative acquaintance use his/her time to do things which are more appealing to her/him.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Here is the thing. I normally test somebody whether they are logical or not using Tower of Hanoi example. If they solve it quick and easily, I think they are logical enough to understand the programming. She was very quick in solving that problem and I thought, hey programming might be right thing for her. The thing I am lagging right now is I don't really have anything to create the interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, unless you're a natural born math-head, recurring patterns of numbers aren't cool.

There's a reason why the canonical thing to start children off with is either turtle graphics, or games programming: it's at least vaguely concrete, and it is open-ended.

Other things people like to make are websites. Some kind of widget-based website framework might appeal.

Comment: Starting with website programming seems like a good idea. However, with the graphics and/or game, most of the programming is based on object-oriented design, something a novice cannot wrap their head around.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Turtle graphics certainly doesn't *require* object orientation. As to the idea that a novice can't understand object orientation, this is a myth which comes about because object oriented technologies have been surrounded with so much mystical mumbo-jumbo. OO is literally just a way of packaging up some variables for use by a related collection of functions, plus some mechanisms to switch out some functions for others.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades I'd add that regardless of your opinion, things targeted at teaching kids do revolve around games and graphics. Even if you think that's necessarily "too hard", people keep doing it, so I suspect they have found otherwise.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades My introduction to programming was a book full of BASIC games you could type in. No OO concepts to worry about, that's for sure. Just a bunch of variables you could tinker with. As a ten-year old, this was just about the best thing in the world.